# C# Taking a specific value from XML string document - child node

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I have a XML string document which basically looks like this:

```
<ItemSpecifics>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Brand</Name>
        <Value>KabelDirekt</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>MPN</Name>
        <Value>514</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>UPC</Name>
        <Value>797698091655</Value>
      </NameValueList>
    </ItemSpecifics>
```

So as you can see I can do something like this:

```
 var doc = new XMLDocument();
 doc.LoadXML(myXML);

var _upcValue = doc.GetElementByTagName("ItemSpecifics"); 
// What to do now ?
```

But I'm not sure how do I retrieve the UPC value from that `Name tag`

The problem continues due to the fact that the UPC value might not be sometimes there but it could be just something like this:

```
   <ItemSpecifics>
          <NameValueList>
            <Name>MPN</Name>
            <Value>514</Value>
          </NameValueList>
    </ItemSpecifics>
```

I know what to do if the tag name was named after the value I'm after, but instead I don't have a clue now how to retrieve it from XML document in form like this, where if the UPC is not present in the string itself..

For cases where UPC is not there I'd simply like to set it to "N/A".

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With LINQ to Xml code can be simpler

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var upcValues = document.Descendants("NameValueList")
                       .Where(pair => pair.Element("Name").Value == "UPC")
                       .Select(pair => pair.Element("Value").Value)
                       .DefaultIfEmpty("n/a");

// upcValues will contain one item "n/a" if no UPC items found
foreach(var upcValue in upcValues) 
{
    // use value
}
```

Comment: Fabio this looks really good, what about the case if i I have more than one "ItemSpecific" Node.. I'd simply want to take out all of the UPC's within all nodes ?

Comment: @User987: you're asking too many questions at a time. This means you're looking for a tutorial rather than an answer to a question.

Comment: @User987, just remove `.First()` and you will get a collection of all values or collection with one item = "n/a" if no upc values found

Comment: @ThomasWeller I forgot to include multiple nodes into the question, sry bout that...

Comment: @Fabio I'm getting this error: cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegat return type

Comment: :) change `.Value = "UPC"` to `.Value == "UPC"` in `Where` statement, suggest to not copy paste code :)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do with LINQ to XML. E.g. you can parse all values to the dictionary:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);
var itemSpecifics = 
    xdoc.Element("ItemSpecifics")
        .Descendants("NameValueList")
        .ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Element("Name"), x => (string)x.Element("Value"));
```

For given xml output will be:

```
{
  "Brand": "KabelDirekt",
  "MPN": "514",
  "UPC": "797698091655"
}
```

Comment: How does this set the UPC to `N/A` if it's not there?

Comment: Dictionary is a data storage. If key is not in dictionary use any value you want, e.g. `itemSpecifics.TryGetValue("UPC", out value) ? value : "N/A"`

Answer (score 1):

Try code below which uses XML Linq to put results into a dictionary.  Code should work with null UPC

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> nameValue = doc.Descendants("NameValueList")
                .GroupBy(y => (string)y.Element("Name"), z => (string)z.Element("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How does this set the UPC to `N/A` if it's not there?

Comment: It will be null.  It you want ?N/A? then z => (z == null)?
 "N/A":(string)z.Element("Value")

Answer (score 1):

When I read XML-files formated like this, I insert all elements to an XmlNodeList with `name = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Name")` and the loop through the lists.
To get the value of Name you do `name[0].InnerText`.